# Matlab Dataset Array Calculating delta t

Tags: arrays, matlab, dataset, timedelta

I have a very large dataset array with over a million values that looks like this:

```
Month Day Year  Hour Min Second   Line1   Line2   Power  Dt
7     8   2013    0   1   54      1.91    4.98    826.8  0
7     8   2013    0   0   9       1.93    3.71    676.8  0
7     8   2013    0   1   15      1.92    5.02    832.8  0
7     8   2013    0   1   21      1.91    5.01    830.4  0
```

and so on. 
  When the measurement of seconds got to 60 it would start over again at 0 hence why the first number is bigger.  I need to fill the delta t column (Dt) by taking the  current rows seconds column and subtracting the previous rows seconds column and correcting for negatyive values.  This opperation cannot preform this operation in a loop as the it would take ages to complete and needs to be completed in a simple, one-shot, vector subtraction operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [diff](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) command to generate such results. Its very fast and should work wihout any for loop.
HTH

Comment: Current.Dt = diff(Current.Second); This is getting me close but if the upper value is larger it gives the wrong number.

Comment: time should be increasing, how the upper value will be larger?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dt=diff(datenum(A(:,1:6)))*60*60*24;
```

This gives the delta in seconds, but I'm not sure what you want you correction for negative differences to be. Could you give an example of the expected output?

Note that Dt will be one entry shorter than A, so you may have to pad it.

You can remove the negative values (I think) with the command

```
Dt(Dt<0)=Dt(Dt<0)+60;
```

If you need to pad the Dt vector so that it is the same length as the data set, try

```
Dt=[Dt;0];
```

Comment: Delta t is the change in time so for example using Current.Dt = diff(Current.Second); on the second and third row (15-9) gives a delta t of 6.  When you use Current.Dt = diff(Current.Second); on the first and second row you get a delta t of (9-54) =-45 which is wrong.  The way the data was collected, once seconds reached 59 the data started over. The true delta t is 15 which is obtained by subtracting (69-54).  because of the way the data was collected, when a larger number precedes a smaller number, it gives an incorrect delta t.  And I dont know how to fix it.

Comment: The name of the dataset is 'Current' by the way.